# Connect UISearchController to UISearchBar without embedding the search bar in the tableview or in the navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, search, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

First of all, sorry if this question sounds too stupid (feel free to skip it).

In my app, I need to create a search area: basically, I should create a search bar and, when the user taps some characters in, I show a tableview with the results.

In my main `ViewController` I did the following:

```
var resultSearchController:UISearchController? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {

         super.viewDidLoad()

         // my results table is 'SearchTable' in my storyboard
         let searchTable = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchTable") as! SearchTable
         resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchTable)
         resultSearchController?.searchResultsUpdater = searchTable as? UISearchResultsUpdating

         resultSearchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
         resultSearchController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
         definesPresentationContext = true
```

Of course, anything works fine if I add the following:

```
let searchBar = resultSearchController!.searchBar
searchBar.sizeToFit()
searchBar.placeholder = "Search..."
// this line embeds the search bar in the navigation bar
navigationItem.titleView = resultSearchController?.searchBar
```

The `UISearchController` creates a `UISearchBar` and sets the search controller's `searchBar` property to it.

Problem is I want a different thing, that is:

1. the search bar should *not* be embedded in the navigation bar;
2. the search bar should *not* be embedded in the tableview itself;

My search bar should be always visible, fixed and placed right below the navigation bar: I simply put an `UISearchBar` in my storyboard, with its constraints and connected it to the viewcontroller as an `IBOutlet`.

But, at this point I don't know how to relate my searchbar to the `resultSearchController`. How could I do? Is it possible?

Comment: What’s your minimum deployment target? (What lowest version of iOS do you need to support)

Comment: I can even support the latest, there's no minimum

Comment: No. Your minimum target is in your Xcode settings of your project. Did you select 11? 12? 10? Cause using searchController is quite different in every iOS versions.

Comment: Glenn, it currently is 12.0 (sorry, I ignored there were those differences)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did all the hard work and the thing that you miss is fairly trivial to what you did.

Basically you should add the `UISearchBar` `resultSearchController!.searchBar` as the subview to the view using the code. I don't think it would be possible with Storyboard, that could be what confused you.

Comment: I couldn't make it work: I can create a UISearchBar in code, I can add it as a subview, but it is completely unrelated to its context. My goal is replacing the default search bar with mine

Comment: I suggested that you should create UISearchController and then its UISearchBar to the view, it seems from your comment that you did something different.

Comment: I'm not understanding: you want to add the searchbar as a subview of the uisearchcontroller? If so, I've not done what you asked

Comment: I want you to add resultSearchController!.searchBar to the main view. Not a new UISearchBar if that's what you did, at least that's what you wrote above.

Comment: Also of note what you might be missing and isn't clear from your code is that your UIViewController cannot be UITableViewController, but rather it must be just UIViewController and you must create and add UITableView from the code or from the Storyboard.

Comment: Ivan, the code you see above is in a UIViewController and the UITableViewController is the searchTable you see in the 4th line of my code. The resultSearchController is created in code (it can't be created with a storyboard). But, and here I don't understand you, the resultSearchController creates its own searchbar: what I want to do is "override" it with my own searchbar.

Comment: That's where I don't understand you or you are missing something. It is true that ' resultSearchController creates its own searchbar', but there is no difference to that searchbar compared to 'your own searchbar' except that it is managed by the controller which is recommended by Apple and in general is what you request to complete the task.

Comment: Anyway, simply adding it this way self.view.addSubview(resultSearchController!.searchBar) causes the following effect: the view appears but if you click inside the textfield, it instantly disappears. This does not happen when use the navigationItem.titleView to display it in the navigation bar

Comment: That's what you should do, however if you set searchResultsController it could be that some of those line cause the behaviour that you see:          resultSearchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
         resultSearchController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true

Comment: Ivan, I found a way, by mixing your suggestion and practical tests: if I create a UIView under my navigation bar and then add resultSearchController!.searchBar as a subview of that view, it works. If I add it directly to the main view it doesn't. Thanks, at least I have something quite working   :-)